# Two data in dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to show employee no as well as employee name in drop down menu.Following codes shows error like "can't convert String into Integer" Is there any way to solve this problem?..

In View

```
<div class="input integer optional"><label class="integer optional control-label" for="assign_staff_subject_id">Subject</label><%= f.select :teacher_id, Teacher.all.map{|i| [i.employee_no,i.id] [i.first_name, i.id]} , :prompt => "--Select a Teacher--" %></div><br/>
```

In which way can I do this? Thank you all in advance

Comment: Try out this `<%= f.select :teacher_id, Teacher.all.map { |i| [i.id, "#{i.first_name} - #{i.employee_no}"] }, :prompt => "--Select a Teacher--" %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to show the first_name and id in the `<li>` tag

```
<%= f.select :teacher_id, Teacher.all.map{|i| ["#{i.first_name}, #{i.id}", "#{i.employee_no},#{i.id}"]} , :prompt => "--Select a Teacher--" %>
```

But if you want to show the employee_no and id in the `<li>` tag

```
<%= f.select :teacher_id, Teacher.all.map{|i| ["#{i.employee_no}, #{i.id}", "#{i.first_name},#{i.id}"]} , :prompt => "--Select a Teacher--" %>
```

Comment: Is there any gem to add state in rails

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this?

```
<%= f.select :teacher_id, Teacher.all.collect {|p| [ "#{p.employee_no} #{p.first_name}", p.id ]} , :prompt => "--Select a Teacher--" %>
```